# Is it important to understand the concept of a universal 'now'?

Tags: special-relativity, particle-physics, cosmology, time-dilation

Is it important to understand the concept of a universal 'now', to explain that time is a local phenomenon, and the rate of time varies throughout the universe, always dependent on the local distribution of mass, and within passing particles dependent on their relative velocity?  I currently think that there is a universal now, but each point in space 'thinks' that it is a different age.  I understand that photons don't age (relative to us) because of their relative speed, and they see their entire path since they were formed, (perhaps in a primordial star) as all squished into a single instant, including my retina as I see it.

Comment: Not just important, but a consequence of how nature was _thought_ to operate. Prior to special relativity, there was no reason to suggest time was relative. Since events in _spacetime_ are frame dependent ("now" for one observer could be in the past or future of another), I'd say that to get to that realization, you would have to already have believed that "now" was the same everywhere and clearly understood the implications of that (incorrect) idea.

Comment: *I currently think that there is a universal now.* There isn’t one in mainstream physics. Personal theories are [off-topic](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on this site.

Comment: Theres one cosmological model, by Mersini-Houghton, that I've heard described as having a sort of central spatio-temporal region where time prevails as an aspect of reality that only "emerges" (as allowing only one direction of passage thru it) as a result of quantum entanglement.  It may be the model described in her book "Before the Big Bang".  Time's widely considered to be an illusion, by physicists who write as beautifully as Rovelli, but is treated as a reality by Smolin (who doesn't), in his book titled "Time Reborn".  A universal now doesn't jive with obs proving Special Relativity.

Comment: Related: [Can there be a theoretical synchronised ‘now’ moment at all points across the universe?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/567130/can-there-be-a-theoretical-synchronised-now-moment-at-all-points-across-the-un)

Comment: There are two sides to your question. (1) The cosmological co-moving time represents what you refer to as “universal now”. It is important to understand *for you*, if you are interested in the subject, but it is nothing new for specialists. (2) In general, science does not define the concept of “now” or “present”. It is subjective. When we talk of “now” right now, we all agree it is May 14, 2023, but those who read this comment tomorrow will disagree.

Answer (score 1):

In some ways yes, and in others no. By analogy, you might ask whether the concept of a universal ground-level was important on Earth. Yes, in the sense that there is a ground level everywhere (if you include sea-beds etc) but ground level varies from place to place- there is no meaningful way in which you can relate ground level in one place to ground level at another. Likewise, no matter where you were in the Universe (I will exclude the insides of black-holes here, in the same way as I would have to exclude the craters of active volcanoes if I were talking about ground level on Earth), you would experience 'now'. However, the 'now' that you experience in one part of the Universe can't be extrapolated in any straightforward way to other places.